# Show Interstitial Ad via AdMob in Ionic every 10 impressionsclick

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob

Show Interstitial Ad via AdMob in Ionic every 10 impressionsclick . i want to show ads after every 10 impressions (screen view).

Answer (score 0):

Use Cordova AdMob plugin for it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

To do what you want:

```
// prepare the Interstitial. You need to load the Ad previously
if(AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {INTERSTICIAL_ID, autoShow:false} );

// Show the loaded Interstitial
if(AdMob) AdMob.showInterstitial();
```

**NOTE:** You should load the intestitial add previously everytime you want to show it. So, before the 10 impressionsclick  you should prepare. When the condition is satisfied, show the Ad.